# Updating maskbit of a physics body in runtime not working ANDENGINE

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, game-physics, 2d-games

I am trying to develop a game like [run! black and white](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.runningmonkey.runbw) in andEngine.
the platform mask bits change on runtime if you look at the game.

to achieve this effect, I am trying to change each platforms mask bit on runtime , something like this.

```
Filter filter1 = new Filter();
                    filter1.maskBits = CATEGORYBIT_NOT_COLLIDE; 
                    single_divider.physics_body.getFixtureList().get(0).setFilterData(filter1);
```

but platforms mask bit does not change on runtime.
I dont know what seems to be the problem. I think the filter data of physics body needs to reset before setting new filter data. But I dont know how.

If anyone can guide me to right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to temporarily turn off colliding the better idea is to use **setSensor()** method

```
    single_divider.physics_body.getFixtureList().get(0).setSensor(true);
```

The sensor is kind of fixtures that detects collision so you can still handle them in the collision listener but the bodies won't collide. [Read more here](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/sensors)

Of course you can also call

```
    single_divider.physics_body.getFixtureList().get(0).setSensor(false);
```

to turn off being sensor (so again turn on colliding)

Comment: thank you so much..it worked..I recommend using sensors to change collision of the body in runtime rather than mask bits and category bits.